# Deploy .war file from another directory to Tomcat 6

Tags: deployment, tomcat6, war

If it is possible, how do I deploy a war file from another directory (say D:\foo.war) to Tomcat 6, without copying it into the webapps directory of Tomcat?

If not, is there any configuration to change the default webapp folder to some other folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do both.

> how do I deploy a war file from another directory (say D:\foo.war) to Tomcat 6, without copying it into the webapps directory of Tomcat?

Add a **Context** xml file to *conf/Catalina/localhost*.  The name of the file should be the name that you want for the context.  For example, if my URL is http://your.domain.com/my-context then the name of the file would be *my-context.xml*.  Inside that XML file add something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context docBase="d:\foo.war">
</Context>
```

The **docBase** attribute should point to your WAR file or an exploded WAR directory.  See more on this [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes).

> If not, is there any configuration to change the default webapp folder to some other folder?

In *conf/server.xml* locate your **Host** tag and set the [**appBase** attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes).  This defaults to *webapps*, but you can change it to any location that you like.

Ex:

```
<Host appBase="d:\my-web-apps" ...>
```

For best results, point to local storage and not network storage (i.e. NFS or Samba).

Comment: I rolled back the change because it's not correct.  To clarify, "Add a Context xml file" is referring to an XML file that contains a <Context> tag, not to a specific file named "Context.xml".  As the instructions go on to state, the name of the file should match the name of the Context.  For example, if your application context name is "/junk", you would add "junk.xml" to the directory indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify a context entry in your server.xml (under `<Host> </Host>`

```
<Context docBase="xyz/abc.war" path="/myapp" reloadable="true"/>
```